# No value for ["read"]

Tags: php, android-volley

I am using volley to pass my data from android studio to an online database. At first the login works fine showing the details of the signed in user (either stylist or client). I am using fragments, the main profile is the first thing that prompts when a successful login occurs, shows then the details. at its side is the edit profile, it also prompts the user details and ready for edit. When its field is replaced then the edit button is clicked, it refreshes back to the main profile fragment then shows this error.

Note: it successfully edits but doesn't show on page reload.

```
Error reading detail org.json.jsonexceotion No value for read
```

"read" is my echoed string array from my php file.

Here it is.

```
<?php 
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){

$id = $_POST['id'];
$userType = $_POST['userType'];
require_once 'connect.php';



    if(strcmp($userType,'Client') == 0){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE client_id=$id";
        $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

        $result = array();
        $result['read'] = array();
        if(mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){
            if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
            $h['name']          = $row['name'];
            $h['phone_number']  = $row['phone_number'];
            $h['gender']        = $row['gender'];
            $h['address']       = $row['address'];
            $h['occupation']    = $row['occupation'];
            $h['birth_date']    = $row['birth_date'];
            $h['user_type']     = $row['user_type'];
            $h['image']                 = $row['photo'];

            array_push($result["read"], $h);

            $result["success"] = "1";

            $result["message"] = "success";
            echo json_encode($result);
            }
        }

}else if(strcmp($userType,'Stylist') == 0){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM stylist WHERE stylist_id=$id";
            $response = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

            $result = array();
            $result['read'] = array();
            if(mysqli_num_rows($response) === 1){
                if($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($response)){
                $h['name']                  = $row['name'];
                $h['phone_number']          = $row['phone_number'];
                $h['gender']                = $row['gender'];
                $h['address']               = $row['establishment_address'];
                $h['occupation']            = $row['stylist_type'];
                $h['birth_date']            = $row['birth_date'];
                $h['user_type']             = $row['user_type'];
                $h['image']                 = $row['photo'];
                $h['verification_photo']    = $row['verification_photo'];
                $h['verification_status']   = $row['verification_status'];

                array_push($result["read"], $h);

                $result["success"] = "1";

                $result["message"] = "success";
                echo json_encode($result);
            }
        }
    }else{
        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "$sql";
        echo json_encode($result);
        }
}
?>
```

And here is my MainProfile fragment.

```
public class MainProfileFragment extends  Fragment{

private static final String TAG = "MainProfileFragment";


private TextView name, birthDate, address, occupation, gender, number, userType, verification_status;
private CircleImageView profile_image;
String getId = " ";
String user_type = " ";
String status = " ";


private static final String URL_READ = "http://isalonbyageeks.000webhostapp.com/readDetail.php";
SessionManager sessionManager;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_mainprofile, container, false);
    return view;

}

@NonNull
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    sessionManager = new SessionManager(getActivity());

    name = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.name);
    number = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.number);
    gender = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.gender);
    address = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.address);
    occupation = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.occupation);
    birthDate = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.birthDate);
    userType = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.userType);
    profile_image = (CircleImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
    verification_status = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.verificationStatus);

    Button logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.logoutBtn);

    HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetail();
    getId = user.get(sessionManager.ID);
    user_type = user.get(sessionManager.USERTYPE);
    status = user.get(sessionManager.VERIFICATION_STATUS);





    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LogoutEffect.class);
            sessionManager.logout();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}


//STYLIST DOESN'T SHOW UP

private void getUserDetail(){
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL_READ,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    Log.i(TAG, response);

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        String success = jsonObject.getString("success");
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");

                        if(success.equals("1")){
                            for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length();i++){

                                JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                                String strName = "Welcome, " +  object.getString ("name").trim();
                                String strNumber = object.getString("phone_number").trim();
                                String strGender = object.getString("gender").trim();
                                String strAddress = object.getString("address").trim();
                                String strOccupation = object.getString("occupation").trim();
                                String strBirthDate = object.getString("birth_date").trim();
                                String strUserType = object.getString("user_type").trim();
                                String strImage = object.getString("image").trim();

                                if(strUserType.equals("Stylist")) {
                                    String strVerStatus = object.getString("verification_status").trim();


                                    if (strVerStatus.equals("Verified")) {
                                        verification_status.setTextColor(getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
                                        verification_status.setText(strVerStatus);
                                    } else if (strVerStatus.equals("Not Verified")) {
                                        verification_status.setTextColor(getActivity().getBaseContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.red));
                                        verification_status.setText(strVerStatus);
                                    } else {
                                        verification_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    verification_status.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                name.setText(strName);
                                    birthDate.setText(strBirthDate);
                                    address.setText(strAddress);
                                    number.setText(strNumber);
                                    gender.setText(strGender);
                                    occupation.setText(strOccupation);
                                    userType.setText(strUserType);
                                if(strImage.equals("")){
                                    profile_image.setImageResource(R.drawable.defaultpic);
                                }else {
                                    Picasso.get().load(strImage).memoryPolicy(MemoryPolicy.NO_CACHE).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.NO_CACHE).into(profile_image);
                                }
                            }
                        }


                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Error Reading Detail " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }
            })
    {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("id", getId);
            params.put("userType", user_type);
            return params;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    getUserDetail();
}

}
```

This should be the json string output

```
{"read":[{"name":"sample","phone_number":"09473642044","gender":"Male","address":"Didto St.","occupation":"Tambay pa","birth_date":"4\/25\/1998","user_type":"Client","image":"https:\/\/isalonbyageeks.000webhostapp.com\/images\/1.jpeg"}],"success":"1","message":"success"}
```

but instead it shows this

```
{"success":"0","message":""}
```

with the following error of No value for read.

What should I change for my `getUserDetails()`?

Comment: Hi Shiela. When you get a moment, please read [How can we encourage (new) authors to ask confident questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366264) Knowing constructive ways to ask for assistance is very useful on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

write getJSONArray code in if success 1 ex: in java file

```
if(success.equals("1")){ JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read"); }
```

or in php file

```
else{ $result['read'] = array(); $result["success"] = "0"; $result["message"] = "$sql"; echo json_encode($result); } }
```

Comment: I have edited just now sir. please look up. It just only sends me the 0 and the error value

Comment: I hope I can sort this out as soon as possible sir :(

Comment: write getJSONArray code in  if success 1 

ex:
in java file
                      `  if(success.equals("1")){
JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("read");
}
`
or
`in php file
else{
$result['read'] = array();
        $result["success"] = "0";
        $result["message"] = "$sql";
        echo json_encode($result);
        }
}
`

Comment: This is the json string output sir :( {"read":[],"success":"0","message":"Error"}

Comment: This should be a comment on the question not an answer!

Comment: echo $userType; return; output ?  in the meantime 'Error reading detail org.json.jsonexceotion No value for read' continues?

Comment: it shows this! "USERTYPE", is it a problem in my sessionmanager? please reply sir!

Comment: try add $userType='Stylist';  before if block. its works ?

Comment: Problem now solved sir! It's from my session! Wrong usage! I will put the answer later myself sir!